# Using match .. case in scala

Tags: scala

I might sound silly but I am new to scala so please bear with me.
I am little confused about using switch case in scala. As per the example of finding the last element of a list

what is the letter 'h' and 'k' is doing ? In short if somebody can explain the below, I will be very grateful.

```
def recLast[A](ls: List[A]): A = ls match {
    case h :: Nil => h
    case b :: rest => recLast(rest)
}
```

Comment: match ... case is used in pattern matching. Here we are reasoning over a linked list - in the first case we look for a match on the last element of the list. The second case removes the head and recurses on the tail. Essentially the function finds the last element in the list by walking it

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, a `List[A]` is an abstract class implemented using singly linked list, composed of a head element of type `A`, and a tail of type `List[A]`. The concrete implementations are `Cons` (`::`), which represents which has a head and a tail, and `Nil` which is the empty list.

What happens in `recLast` is that the `List[A]` is decomposed using a feature called Pattern Matching. The `case` denotes a pattern which we attempt to match on.

The first case:

```
case h :: Nil => h
```

Means "In case the `List[A]` contains a head element `h` and a tail which is the empty list (called `Nil`), then return the head element.

The second case

```
case b :: rest => recLast(rest)
```

Means "In case the `List[A]` contains a head element which we bind to `b` and a `tail` which we bind to `rest`, take the tail of the list and recursively call `recLast` with it.

One way of pattern matching on a `List[A]` is using the `Cons` class. By doing `head :: tail`, which call the `::.apply` method in infix notation, it is equivalent to: `::.apply(head, tail)`

#### Appendix

The concrete implementation of the classes:

`::` (Cons):

```
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, 
                       private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

`Nil`:

```
case object Nil extends List[Nothing] {
  override def isEmpty = true
  override def head: Nothing =
    throw new NoSuchElementException("head of empty list")
  override def tail: List[Nothing] =
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("tail of empty list")
  override def equals(that: Any) = that match {
    case that1: scala.collection.GenSeq[_] => that1.isEmpty
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the case statement does pattern matching  if the list has one element (i.e. it is  :: Nil it would be matched for the first case and  would be assigned to h the latter case does the same thing and also assigned the rest (tail) to "rest"

you can also see this pattern matching if you write the following in the REPL

```
scala> val h :: rest = List(1,2,3,4)
h: Int = 1
rest: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```